# Highlight an item in a UIList

Tags: python

I have a UIList in which I list materials to which I have attached an additional EnumProperty.

My goal is to highlight items in this UIList based on this EnumProperty by changing their background color. Is this possible?

I guess something like

```
if item.my_enum == "target_value":
    #I guess here i have to use something instead of layout.prop()?
```

in the draw_item() function is necessary?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the colors of items in the UI-List, arbitrarily.

You can however have an "active" property, which is an index that defines the active item in the UI list (as is used for vertex groups, uv layers... etc).

See the **UI List** template in the text editor.